# Weird Game Center bug

Tags: ios, game-center

So the bug is this.  Set a high score, then open up the GKScoreboard.  After you close it

> APP Name[9879:986183] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated

will appear on the console.  After that you can no longer set a high score. What could be causing this?

Edit: I have just replaced the code for displaying the leaderboard with examples from SO.  It still happens.

Edit: I just noticed that it actually won't allow me to open UIAlertViews when on the scene with the leaderboard button.  It gives me the following message:

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
```

Comment: Have you done [a search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plugin+com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension+)?

Comment: Yes.  Most people get it when the view won't pop up.  The apple forms one has yet to be resolved